# How to change diplayed list by selecting a button?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to diplay a list of persons.
All persons have a list of team ids and a list of roles.
The diplaying list should only contain persons that have a role "player" and should be in the selected team.

It works for the first team, but if I try to select another team, it shows no or only one person.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private personService: PersonService){  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTeams();
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  getPlayers(){
    this.personService.getPersons().subscribe((persons: Person[])=>{    
      // set image if unset
      for(var i=0; i < persons.length; i++){
        if(persons[i]["image"] == ""){
          persons[i]["image"] = "assets/images/player.jpg";
        }
      }
      this.persons = persons;
    })
  }

  getTeams(){
    this.personService.getTeams().subscribe((teams: Team[])=>{
      this.teams = teams;
      this.selectedTeam = this.teams[0];
      this.load(this.selectedTeam);
    })
  }

  load(team:Team){
    if(this.selectedTeam.id != team.id){
      this.selectedTeam = team;
      console.log(this.selectedTeam);
    }
  }

}
```

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'PersonRole'
})
export class PersonRolePipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(persons: Person[], role: string) {
    return persons.filter(person => person.roles.includes(role) === true) as Person[];
  }

}
```

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'PersonTeam'
})
export class PersonTeamPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(persons: Person[], team: Team) {
    return persons.filter(person => person.teams.includes(team.id) === true) as Person[];
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="teams-switch">
      <shape-button
        *ngFor="let team of teams"
        [label]="team.name"
        theme="accent"
        (click)="load(team)">
      </shape-button>
  </div>

  <ngx-slick-carousel 
    class="carousel"
    #slickModal="slick-carousel"
    [config]="slideConfig">

    <shape-person-card
    ngxSlickItem 
    *ngFor="let person of persons | PersonRole:'player' | PersonTeam:selectedTeam" 
    class="slide item"

    [tag]="person.tag"
    [name]="person.name"
    [image]="person.image"

    [socialmedia]="person.socialmedia">
    </shape-person-card>

  </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

Comment: what do those pipes do? Guessing they're some kind of filtering pipe, and this is one of the reasons you shouldn't actually do things this way

Comment: they just filter the persons

Comment: yea, shouldn't make filtering pipes for this reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your PersonRole and PersonTeam pipes are both sort of filtering pipes, that may be mutating the existing array, or otherwise not change detecting properly because pipes are generally considered "pure" meaning they only run when the input changes, but the input here isn't changing, just the parameters.

instead, do the filtering logic where it belongs, in your component:

```
filteredPersons = [];
filterPersons() {
  if (this.selectedTeam && this.persons) {
    // using mutative method bc ngx-slick is lame
    this.filteredPersons.length = 0;
    // you could probably do the players filtering in the beginning when you get the persons array for optimization
    this.persons.filter(p => p.roles.includes('player') && p.teams.includes(this.selectedTeam.id))
                .forEach(p => this.filteredPersons.push(p));
  }
}

trackById(index, person){
  return person.id; // for use in trackBy
}

load(team:Team){
  if(this.selectedTeam.id != team.id){
    this.selectedTeam = team;
    console.log(this.selectedTeam);
    this.filterPersons();
  }
}
```

then your html is:

```
*ngFor="let person of filteredPersons; trackBy: trackById"
```

Comment: still the same issue and now I don't even get the right team displayed in the beginning

Comment: seems like an issue in ngx-slick-carousel then, peaked at the docs and they seem to only mutate an array rather than re assign... they have a note recommending a trackBy function so I added that to my answer.. if that doesn't fix it, I'll show you how to do this with mutation

Comment: alright, try it with the mutative methods in the answer now. and log the array after the filter runs to make sure it's populated correctly

Comment: It works, the only problem is that in the begining there is no team selected

Comment: it's probably a timing issue between the teams and persons loading. add the null check into the filter function that i edited in, and call filterPersons() at the end of getPlayers() after you assign the persons array

Comment: The selectedTeam is set but it is not diplaying it

Comment: it won't if the persons get there after the team.  it's a timing problem, so you need to address it

Comment: I have a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597921/how-to-fix-not-loading-elements-bug-in-angular-chrome